# Prove $[N(H):H]\equiv [G:H] \pmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $|H|=p^n$ for some $p$ prime, $n\geq1$. Show that $[N(H):H]\equiv [G:H]\pmod p$.

I observed that I will need to show that $p$ divides $\dfrac{|G|-|N(H)|}{p^n}$. However as of now I do not know any relationship between $N(H)$ and $|G|$. Some hint is appreciated.

Comment: I would advise considerig the cases when $p$ does and does not divide $|G:H|$ separately, If it does, then $H$ is strictly contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, and then $N_P(H)$ strictly contains $H$, so $p$ divides $|N(H):H|$. Otherwise $H$ is itself a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, in which case $|G:N(H)|$ is the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups, which is equal to $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: Hello Derek, thank you for the comment! However, would it be possible to solve this problem without using Sylow's Theorem at all? I have completed upto Isomorphisms in Abstract Algebra. I haven't studied Cayley's Theorem or Sylow's Theorems or Finitely generated Abelian groups. Maybe you could guide me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: you can prove by applying the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem and showing first that the number of invariant cosets under the action of $H$ by left-multiplication on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ equals index$[N_G(H):H]$.